# IIS 8 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

Is it (or will it be) possible to install IIS 8 on Windows Server 2008 (R2) or it's only meant for Windows Server "8"/2012?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Traditionally, it's always been one version of IIS to one operating system.

- Windows XP - IIS 5.1
- Server 2003 - IIS 6
- Server 2008 - IIS 7
- Server 2008 R2 - IIS 7.5

I see no sign of this changing in the immediate future.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it *is* possible to install IIS 8, on Windows 2008, Windows 7 and Windows Vista, see [IIS 8 Express Readme](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-80-express-readme). However, this is the Express Edition, which is meant (as TomTom points out below) as an edition for developers.

Not sure whether the OP wanted IIS 8 in a production environment, or just for testing, developing or experimenting. In the latter case, you could [just download and install it](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29937).

Note that some of the prime features of IIS 8 are not be available on the down-level platforms. Specifically, these are mentioned by Microsoft as *not available* on platforms before Windows 2012:

- Server Name Indication (SNI)
- Central Certificate Store
- WebSocket Functionality

Comment: -1. hadly outdated given that the Express Edition is a "developer tool" and not a production web Server.

Comment: @TomTom, you are right, it was a poor choice of words. However, the OP asks whether he can install IIS 8 on Win2k8 and he can, and the original answer doesn't reflect that. I changed the text to reflect the limitations better.